# How to use icon font with HTML entities when Thymeleaf escapes ampersand for XML validation?

Tags: xml, spring, thymeleaf, icon-fonts

I'm trying to use Icomoon web icon font in a Spring Thymeleaf application. 
The recommended method is to set a data-icon attribute in an HTML tag. 
The given css then sets font family to icomoon and content to the value of the data-icon attribute, using the selector [data-icon]:before.

The icons are references by HTML Entity Code (&#xe048 for example).

I guess you've spotted my issue, Thymeleaf templates are XHTML documents. So we got a problem with the ampersand. It is escaped at template rendering to &amp. The icons cannot be rendered this way...

How can I prevent Thymeleaf from escaping it ?

Comment: Are you sure that you get xe048? It's not a valid Unicode character. And shouldn't there be a semicolon?

Comment: Yes, there is a semicolon, see http://d.pr/i/MPvD